# Как узнать исходный код программы?

Tags: c++

Нужно узнать исходный код программы, написанной на C++. (Почему именно на с++? - Не спрашивайте, просто знаю и всё.) Для особо любознательных говорю, что программа эта является читом для css и мне не только интересно, как она работает, но ещё я бы хотел её чуть-чуть исправить, потому что как только ты убиваешь кого-либо, то она в чатике пишет headshot, а меня это бесит.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ну исходный код на С++ ты ни как не получишь, а вот дизассемблировать вполне можно. погляди на [IDA Pro](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA). лучше инструмента под Windows я не видел. Если изменить ход программы нужно совсем чуток, то можешь воспользоваться [OllyDbg](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OllyDbg). И прямо на ходу изменить ассеблерные команды в нужном месте и сохранить новый дамп.

Уроки и статьи по дизассемблированию можешь найти на [wasm.ru](http://wasm.ru).

Answer (score 7):

*Насчет дизассемблирования вам уже ответили, скажу чуть подробнее по самой проблеме.*

В том случае, если `exeшник` `aimbot'а` никак не запакован *(в таком случае необходимо руками снять соответствующий пакер*), то строковые константы обычно хранятся в одной части файла и все вместе.

Т.е, вполне вероятно, что даже без использования `IDA` для реверсинга, можно в любом `hex-`редакторе подправить неустраивающую вас строчку (`headshot`) на что-либо менее заметное.

Answer (score 5):

Для получения исходного кода используйте дизассемблер. IDA - лучший дизассемблер из все, которые я пробовал. У него есть тестовая версия, профессиональная (платная) и расширенная (бесплатная).

Answer (score 3):

Вы сможете "вытянуть" исходный код только в Ассемблере. Еще можете попробовать программу - редактор ресурсов для изменения headshot на другое сообщение, хотя далеко не факт, что будет возможность.

Comment: Можно получить ассемблерный листинг но это будет не *исходный* код

Answer (score 3):

если нужно именно на С++, то никак.
можешь дизассемблеризировать, но код на Си++ вы никак не получите.
хотя, с другой стороны, если найти аналог программы, которая распространяется бесплатно(я имею ввиду GNU), то можно просто скачать исходники.

Answer (score 1):

Слышал, существуют декомпиляторы, но, по-моему, не для C++, а для C. Они ничем тебе не помогут, потому что, получившийся код не всегда можно откомпилировать и он будет почти таким же непонятным, как и на ассемблере.

Ещё, как вариант, можно взломать компьютер автора кода и переписать его себе. Только тогда ты сможешь узнать код в том виде, в котором он написан.

Comment: Зачем минусовать-то? Каков вопрос, таков ответ.